# Remove files and code in dev branch only but keep them in master when merging

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I’m working on an iOS app and have a 3rd party framework that is only built for certain architectures such that it does not allow execution of my app tests or the iOS simulator. I cannot seem to get weak framework linking working so I thought I can just remove the framework and it’s usage in a dev branch for testing and development but keep the framework in the master branch for releases.

The problem is that when I remove it from the dev branch, and then dev new features that I want to merge to master, the deletion of the framework usage gets merged as well. This makes sense, but I’m looking for a way around it.

Is this possible with git?

Comment: I think your fundamental problem is that the 3rd party framework should not be included in master, either.  You are abusing git by using it this way.  However, you could simply rebase your dev branch to remove the commit that removes the framework before you merge.

Comment: What is the alternative to solve the fundamental problem? Basically I need the framework in the releases but it gets in the way during development of features that don’t use it.

Comment: You need a release process.  Using git to distribute the software is *not* a good approach.

Comment: I am not using git for distribution, the way I spoke was misleading. I meant that basically I needed a way to run my app in the simulator and unit tests WITHOUT those frameworks since those frameworks arent built to support the simulator, and at the same time i need to be able to run my app on real devices WITH those frameworks since they are needed to test functionality on real hardware. Your cautions led me to look for an alternate solution and I ended up figuring out how to use conditional compiling to ignore the frameworks when running in a "test" configuration. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, Git is not involved with build/release process.
What you can do is versioned a build script which

- is able to determine in which Git branch it is currently executed

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref HEAD)
  ```
- will create a symlink to your framework in the source if that branch is `master`
  Or will delete that symlink if that branch is not `master`.